# Implementing periodic boundary conditions of PDE integrator in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, pde

I need to implement in C++ a finite-differences integrator of a partial differential equation. In Python I used the `numpy.roll` method to roll the array and thus obtain periodic boundary conditions.

Is there an a library in C that will give me this method? That is, that when I access the position `n+1` of a vector of length `n` it will point to the cell at location `0` of the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mod operator to adjust the index.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int roll(vector<int>& v, unsigned int n) {
   return v[n % v.size()];
}

int main() {
   vector<int> v;
   for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
      v.push_back(i);
   }

   return roll(v, 2);
}
```

To roll the entire vector, use this function:

```
vector<int> rollVector(const vector<int>& v, unsigned int n) {   
   auto b = v.begin() + (n % v.size());
   vector<int> ret(b, v.end());
   ret.insert(ret.end(), v.begin(), b);
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: So roll(v, 2) suppose to give me the whole vector rolled by 2 indexes?

Comment: No, a new vector is not created. Just the index where i >= n is mapped to the correct value. The example above `roll(v, 11)` would return v[1].